# I edited the post but someone else got attributed for it

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, attribution

Ok, this is weird. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875080/php-how-to-array-unshift-on-an-arrayobject/6875261#6875261) I corrected the issue of placing code after a list by placing `<!-- -->` between the code and the list.

After committing I noticed that I added an extra space at the beginning of each of the code lines so I clicked edit again in order to remove those spaces.

However, I couldn't "edit my edit" (which you normally can) and clicked cancel. When I went back to the page, the edit was attributed to someone else.

Since I copied the post and made the edition in a desktop markdown editor, I had a copy of my edition and diff compared that "cached" copy with the edition accepted, which resulted in the texts being exactly the same (no diff at all).

I reckon that a bug must have occurred since the edit was attributed to someone else and I didn't get any reputation.

Comment: Your edit was probably rejected and the reviewer went ahead and further edited it.

Comment: Don't edit to get credit, edit it to improve the post.

Comment: @hims056 That has nothing to do with it. I'm reporting a possible bug, not complaining about not getting +2 rep. Reporting bugs is useful, is it not?

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah yes, another thing. No history of my edit.

Comment: @Tivie: No, I was looking at the wrong list. [This is the correct list](http://stackoverflow.com/users/295342/tivie?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Comment: @hims056 Then how would you put it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1136398

The user [phant0m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383124/phant0m) reviewed your edit. He chose to "improve", but ***unchecked*** the "helpful" box.

---

[image]

---

[image]

The result is that your edit is rejected and phant0m's edit overrides yours.

Comment: In this specific case, phant0m did not improve anything. The edits are verbatim the same.

Comment: Then I dunno. He had to have unchecked the "helpful" box.

Comment: @MartijnPieters He added backticks to one word more, so the edits are different, though not different enough to declare the previous one unhelpful and then still edit yourself. It could also be an edit collision, though it doesn't really look that way in my opinion.

Comment: Ah I see. But shouldn't he need to add "something"? His edit is exactly the same as mine

Comment: @Tivie Could be a mistake. Last week, I also managed to somehow reject someone else's edit, even though I didn't consciously uncheck the box.

Comment: @MadScientist: ah, indeed. I need a diff view for diff views..

Comment: @MartijnPieters What exactly happens if you submit an edit when there is a pending suggested edit?

Comment: @Mysticial: The pending edit is rejected by Community. But note that the suggested edit page states phant0m responded to the suggested edit with an `Edit` action, so he did uncheck the 'helpful' box.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So in other words, this could also be an edit collision. It was rejected within 50 seconds. EDIT: Yes, it does say "Edit". That's where I initially found the link. Hmm...

Comment: He didn't receive any reputation for the edit though. Shouldn't he?

Comment: @Mysticial: No, not in this case; it could be phant0m found the edit when viewing the post.

Comment: @Tivie: not an exploit, no. It's a valid feature of the system.

Comment: @Tivie He has more than 2k. You don't get rep for edits when you have the edit privilege.

Comment: @Tivie: No, only suggested edits give you reputation. Once you can edit posts directly (2k+) you do it to improve the site, not for reputation. You should do it for improving the site too.

Comment: I do of course. +2 rep is hardly an extreme incentive =P I was stating that fact because I didn't know of that rule and though it might be relevant to the bug theory.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So, you're positive this is the intended behavior and there's no bug? Should I mark Mysticals answer as correct?

Comment: @Tivie: Mysticals answer is correct; there is *no* bug.